# Checked out documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, check-out

I've got a weird one, we have a document list and I've added a view to show all items checked out, one document I know if checked out but it doesn't appear in the list as checked out I know it is because when I try to open it pop up says read only as document is checked out to another user.

Any ideas how to make this visible with a view of all checked out items?

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that this document was never checked out at least once, so it will be visible only to the author, you need to ask author to check it once at least once.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default for items that have NEVER been checked in. This could happen when someone uploads an item without filling in required metadata (usually through windows explorer).

It's also possible that versioning is enabled on the library and someone created a checked-out minor-version.

There is a view for administrators inside the library settings area specifically to locate these items.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the document is currently in the short term checkout. This lock is applied by the office client and is not visible as a real checkout.

Try to use Powershell and examine the object directly. Look at this:

SPFile.SPCheckOutStatus

It should be short term...

Answer (score 0):

Try to build a view that ignores Folders and files and filters out by the CheckOut To column not being NULL - This would mean in reality the document is CheckedOut.

This does not require any code change

e.g 
Create a View with a filter. The condition for the filter can be stated as below:

Select field "Checked-out to" 
Condition "Is not equal to" 
and keep the value field Empty/Blank